# How to parse a text block from mysql as php code in page?

Tags: php

For some reason, my code is not evaluating. That is, I see raw code in my table as text

```
preg_match('@<h1 class="title"  itemprop="name">(.*?)<\/h1>@sim',$source,$title);
```

How do I make this code **execute** for my page?

Comment: What does that even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with [eval php function](http://www.php.net/eval) ? it evaluates the string and execute it as if it is code

Comment: Thank you. That's the answer! 

eval($string) works.